# ¿Cuál es la mejor manera para almacenar una imagen en la base de datos SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, imagen, uwp

Tengo una aplicación en UWP y quiero mostrar imágenes, pero esas imágenes tengo que guardarlas en la base de datos, no quiero usar una URL de almacenamiento, quiero no de-serializarlas, subirlas serializadas a la base de datos y traerla y de-serializarlas. solo que no se que tipo de campo usar y en que se pueden serializar.

Comment: para comunicar la app UWP con la DB que estas usando? o sea tienes una web api o similar, intercambias datos usando json

Comment: Si uso una API y las consultas las traigo en Json desde Azure

Comment: @Wilmilcard **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. Debes [edit] y mejorar tu pregunta. Agrega en la pregunta qué has intentado, qué errores tienes, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si usas una `webapi` podrias enviar la imagen serializada a `base64`, usando algo como esto

```
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
```

entonces al tener el string de la imagen podrias ponerlo como parte del json que envies al invocar la webapi

Del lado de la webapi usarias

```
byte[] array = Convert.FromBase64String(imageString);
```

para tener el byte array que usarias en el parametro del INSERT que realizarias en la db (o en la propiedad de la clase si usas entity framework)

Si usas alguna libreria para serializar como ser `json.net` podrias aplicar algo como esto

[How do I Serialize object to json using json.net which contains an image property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370046/how-do-i-serialize-object-to-json-using-json-net-which-contains-an-image-propert)

basicamente es una clase conversora que le indica en la serializacion como tratar la propiedad de la imagen

```
public class ImageConverter : JsonConverter
{
    //implementacion
}
```

en la clase la usas

```
public class Person
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ImageConverter))]
    public Image photo { get; set; }
}
```